# With Modelsim .do file, how to compile a list of files using vcom

Tags: tcl, vhdl, fpga, modelsim

In an Modelsim .do file,
I tried:

```
vcom file1.vhd file2.vhd
```

which works fine.

But when I try:

```
set comp_files "file1.vhd file2.vhd"
vcom $comp_files
```

it didn't work and I got an error:

> Error: (vcom-7) Failed to open design unit file "file1.vhd file2.vhd" in read mode.

Anyone know how to get the comp_files worked?

Comment: .do files are tcl scripts. Have you looked at a tcl language reference? There ought to be one in the Modelsim documentation.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I tried but I can't find a solution to my pb. I do this because I want to categorize my vhdl files like : design_files, testbench_files, XXX_files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to expand the list `comp_files` to individual arguments using `{*}` (Tcl 8.5):

```
set comp_files "file1.vhd file2.vhd"
vcom {*}$comp_files
```

Alternatively, you can use the legacy `eval` (should also work with Tcl versions < 8.5):

```
set comp_files "file1.vhd file2.vhd"
eval vcom $comp_files
```

Answer (score 1):

So: `set comp_files "file1.vhd file2.vhd"` creates a list.

try `llength $comp_files` And it will return "2" = two elements.

So you can call vcom for each file in the list

```
foreach comp_file $comp_files { vcom $comp_file }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it tells me `** Error: can't read "comp_file": no such variable`

Comment: @CongLi hmm, strange. Are you sure you did not mistype something? Works fine here.

Comment: Technically, the first `set` command creates a string; the string gets parsed and interpreted as a list as soon as its passed as an argument to the first command expecting to receive a list. So if one wants to be absolutely sure (and that's a good thing!), it's better to use the `list` command explicitly: `set comp_files [list file1.vhd file2.vhd]`

Comment: @kostix of course, there's always a better way. Just telling the OP a possible solution